# linq-to-sql performance issues when binding to custom models

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

**Edit**

After doing a bit of looking around into my own code, I come to realized the problem wasn't the linq performance issues as much as I accidently removed a section of code that. My Apologizes, Thanks all :D

**Original post**

I am wandering about performance issues with linq to SQL. At the moment I do something like this:

```
var rslts = datacontext.People.AsQueryable();
foreach(var v in rslts)
    list.Add(new PersonModel(v)) //I do this because i need the model to have properties that are not in the linq model
```

then assign the list to a wpf datagrid, and Person Model is something like this:

```
LINQModels.Person _person;
public PersonModel(LINQModels.Person person)
{
   _person = person;
}

 public string FirstName
 {
       get{return _person.firstname;}
       set
       {
           if(value == _person.firstname)
                return;   
           _person.firstname = value;
       }
 }
  .... and so on;
```

Now initially, I used the simple database queries "SELECT * " etc and then built the models manually from the results returned, then I decided to use linq, hence I have ended up with the code below, however there is a Major performance drop since i changed to the linq method, even when I simply scroll through the results in the datagrid O.o it stutters badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the classes from Linq-to-sql because they are partial classes so you can just..

```
public partial People
{
    // custom methods & properties that aren't auto generated by linq
}
```

Comment: ahh didn't realize that, it will help but in some areas but I am not sure itll fix my whole performace issue. Thanks Tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "do this because i need the model to have properties that are not in the linq model". Why do you need to have them in the LINQ model if they relate to the LINQ model?

```
[Table(...)]
public class MyTableClass
{
  [Column(...)]
  int RelatesToColumn{get;set;}

  int DoesntRelateToColumn
  {
    get { return RelatesToColumn + 42; }
  }
}
```

Also, do you really need a list with the data grid? I'm not that familiar with WPF's grid, but could you not just use `datacontext.People.AsEnumerable().Select(v => new PersonModel(v));` ?

More generally, there can be performance gotchyas with LINQ2SQL, though there are also a good few times where a small amount of LINQ would require a large amount of hand-optimising to beat in other approaches. The main thing is to think about what each query is doing, and to have enough modesty in this to not assume you got such thinking right every time, so you examine the actual SQL (and in turn, the execution plan) on critical points.

Comment: maybe "propeties" isn't the right word, but its to do with how the program interacts with the data, for example drop down menu lists and so on, the problem isn't with the query and search times, its more to do with binding the result to a ViewModel( a better desrciption sorry ), the results return fast enough its when I bind the results to the ViewModel, ill try reword the question to make it more accurate.